# Can I use a batch file to remove blank columns in a .csv

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, csv

I have nine columns in my current .csv file, however, the 2nd and 3rd columns are blank and I want to get rid of them. Is there a way to use batch commands to remove these empty columns from my .csv or export a new .csv without those blank columns?

Comment: Please edit your question to confirm: (1) Are you running Windows? (2) If so, are you looking for a pure Windows batch solution, or are you open to other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For /F` is capable of parsing a .csv file. In one line, to be run directly from the command prompt:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=," %i in (input.csv) do @echo %i,%l>>output.csv
```

This traverses input.csv line for line and using a comma as delimiter, stores the first value in `%i`, the second in `%j`, the third in `%k` and the rest of the string (by using an asterisk in the list of tokens) in `%l`. By printing all but the second and third values, you are effectively taking those out.

However, `for /F` does not count empty strings as tokens, so the command cannot differentiate between two subsequent commas and a single one. This solution does work if the empty columns have a whitespace character, but may skip the wrong columns otherwise.

To circumvent this restriction, we can write a batch file that uses string replacement to insert a space between two subsequent commas. This replacement is executed twice to cope with the possibility of three commas. The quotes in `^"!line!^"` are required to indicate `for /F` has to operate on a string instead of a file and are escaped to prevent `!line!` from being evaluated as a literal string instead of a variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.csv) do (
    set line=%%a
    set line=!line:,,=, ,!
    set line=!line:,,=, ,!
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=," %%i in (^"!line!^") do (
        echo %%i,%%l>>output.csv
    )
)
```

The result is a new .csv file, identical to input.csv, except for the omitted second and third columns.

Comment: Note that this will add blanks to empty fields in columns other than 2 and 3.  For example, `The,quick,brown,fox,,,the,lazy,dog` will become `The,,,fox, , ,the,lazy,dog`.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify which OS. If yours comes with `cut`, use this.

```
cut -d',' -f1,4-9
```

`-d` sets the delimiter, in this case to a `,`. Since comma is not a special character, you can omit the quotes.
`-f` selects the fields, in this case field 1 and fields 4 till 9 (skipping fields 2 and 3).

```
Testfile "example.cvs"
foo1,   ,   , ba1, baz1, blah1, wibble1, wubble1
foo2,   ,   , ba2, baz2, blah2, wibble2, wubble2
foo2,   ,   , ba3,     , blah3, wibble3, wubble3
foo2,   ,   , ba4, baz4, blah4, wibble4, wubble4
```

An actual test of the command:

```
> cut -d',' -f1,4-9 example.cvs

foo1, ba1, baz1, blah1, wibble1, wubble1
foo2, ba2, baz2, blah2, wibble2, wubble2
foo2, ba3,     , blah3, wibble3, wubble3
foo2, ba4, baz4, blah4, wibble4, wubble4
```

Cut comes preinstalled with most operating systems (e.g., OS/X, Linux distributions, BSDs, Solaris, ...; just about everyone except DOS and Windows).

If you have Windows, you can:

1. Open the CVS file in a spreadsheet (e.g., [OpenOffice Calc](http://www.openoffice.org/) or MS Excel), delete two columns, and then save the file. Hard to automate though, so use only if you need to do it once or rarely.
2. or download [Unix tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2391) and put the `cut` command in a batch file.

Comment: My OS is Windows. Unfortunately, I would want this as an automated process since this is a .csv that's created everyday in the same format. Are there other alternatives for windows OS?

Comment: You can install a cut command (e.g. from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm ), or you can try something with for. An example of using for is `for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %i in (file.txt) DO echo %i`

Comment: Unless you know the maximum number of columns, use `-f1,4-` to include _all_ columns after the third.  `4-` means `4-∞`.

Comment: True. I based my `-f4-9` on the first sentence of the OP post "I have nine columns", but `-f4-` is more flexible less less typing. An other option would have been to used `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I would open the CSV file in Notepad (or any text editor) and search and replace `,,` with `,`. This, of course, is assuming the data in your columns do not have `,,` in them.

Comment: That will corrupt the structure of the file if any of the other columns have any empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, the file has no headers, and you have Powershell available to you, you can use something like the following:

> Import-Csv .\InFile.csv -Header col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 -Delimiter ',' | Select-Object col1,col4,col5 | ConvertTo-Csv | Select -skip 2 > .\OutFile.csv

So it:

- Imports the CSV.
- Assigns column names for reference.
- Selects all 5 columns, except 2 and 3.
- Converts back to a proper CSV.
- Selects that CSV, starting at line 2 (to skip the assigned column headers)
- Pipes it out to an output file.